# REGEXP_LIKE. Составление регулярного выражения для отбора корректно EMAIL

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Есть задача составления регулярного выражения для отсечения не корректных EMAIL адресов которые не попадают под общие правила ведения почтовых адресов. В целом написал конструкцию следующую:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$
```

Но так или иначе проходит мусор по типу:

```
+79265366817msm@gmail.com , _____________@hotel-best.com
```

Есть ли возможность скорректировать данное выражение? Все мои попытки корректировки приводят к отсечению корректной инфы.

Comment: Все уже [придумали](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201378/15035314) до нас :)